# Google map background is gray

Tags: javascript, html, modal-dialog

I have created a modal, where i want to appear a google map. I took the code from w3schools, and adapted to my code but the background is gray. I have saved the file in php, but mos of code is in html and javascript. I used the same code of the map in a simple html file and it workes. Why it doesnt work for me?

```
<div class="leftModal" id="map" style="width:50%;height:300px;float:left;">
      </div > //this is the div where i want to add the map, i havent included other part of code

<script>    
var mapCanvas = document.getElementById("map");
 var mapOptions = { center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.323370, 19.812035), zoom: 10 } var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
</script>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

[should look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPFF5.png)

[but it looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OcBCl.png)

Comment: it would help to post the code you have tried

Comment: var mapCanvas = document.getElementById("map");
var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.323370, 19.812035), zoom: 10
}
var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions); //this is in the script 
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>  
and i have a div with id="map" in the modal body. 
it appears the google map box but its gray  @mlegg

Comment: i dont know how to post a code here, i have already signed up :/

Comment: edit your question and post your code by clicking on the code snippet link, or use CTRL + M  http://postimg.org/image/m9x65230b/

Comment: @mlegg thank you for your info, i just put the javascipt code so you catch the idea. I tried it in a simple file and it works both in .html or .php, but it doesnt work in the pop up modal that i have created.

Comment: where is the css for the modal window? go to http://codepen.io/ and create a new pen with all the html, css, javascript,   look at this what to click to start http://s33.postimg.org/427u0mqfj/Capture.png

Comment: @mlegg I am sorry but i do not know how to use CodePen, and i do not have much time to spend to figure it out, so i just entered the images  how it should look and how it looks in my question above.

Comment: @mlegg i put the same code in another part of my page, not at the modal and it worked perfectly fine. Maybe the modal causes some problem with the map.

Comment: can you edit your original post and add the css there? use the method I posted the image above with, use CTRL + M. Without seeing that there is no way to figure out your problem

Comment: @mlegg You are right, i wasn't being clear at all. I really thank you for trying to help me. The thing was that it was a lot of code, especially css and javascript. It seems that maps, have an issue when you try to resize them, and in the modal from "display:none" to "display:block" this issue was created. I didnt know that because i am knew to web technologies. To conclude, i didn't use trigger from bootstrap because i do not know why it didn't work well. I just substituted "display attribute" with "visibility" and worked perfectly fine! Sorry for the long answer,Wish you all the best :)

Comment: Do you have a working page on the internet so I can view all of the code?

Comment: No, this is just a project for school, and i have not put it in the school server yet. @mlegg but you can look at http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp where i was based for my modal, because bootstrap is not allowed in the proj.

Comment: check this out http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-For-Google-Maps-API-Manipulation-Google-Map/

Comment: @mlegg thank you, but i said to you that i fixed it.I will use your reference if i need it anytime :)